# Best approach to store rich text with images to Core Data?

Tags: swift, macos, core-data, rich-text-editor

Is storing `NSAttributedText` including `NSTextAttachment` for images, or `NSTextStorage` into `Core Data` as binary data a good solution **performance-wise**?

Do I need to store it as `Binary Data`or is there a better alternative? Maybe `Transformable`? Consider that I need to save it **while typing**, and this should **sync in iCloud** with a test editor on iOS.

If not, what would be the best practice to store rich text documents in my app?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In most cases it is no good practice to store large binary objects in a database. Especially if you write such objects very often (*while typing*) you stress the database more than necessary. Why not store the data in a file and use the database just for metadata?

With a CloudKit container you can share the files between devices like you already do with the database. Maybe you can the store the `NSAttributedText` in HTML format, so the files can even be read without your app.

Comment: and storing/retrieving files to/from the hard disk is a wise choice performance wise? I thought core data was faster.

Comment: For example the macOS Notes app is saving the notes in a sqlite database.